# Web API error 500 from method

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an Angularjs front end and a Web API backend.

I'm getting an error 500 from a method when returned object contains a list.No problem when the list is not present :

If I return an object like this there is no error :

```
var myObj = new { name1 = value1, name2 = value2};
return myObj;
```

But for the following I got and error 500 :

```
var q = from p in db.SomeThing select p;
var MyObj =  new { name1 = value1, name2 = value2, name3 = q.ToList()};
```

Some error 500 for :

```
var q = from p in db.SomeThing select p;
var MyObj =  new { name1 = value1, name2 = value2, name3 = q};
```

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entities returned from `db.SomeThing` my have navigation properties that are causing the exception when they are executed during serialization. Try selecting an anonymous object instead of `p` and see if that solves your problem.

```cs
var q = from p in db.SomeThing 
        select new { 
            property1 = p.property1, 
            property2 = p.property2,
            //other properties
        };
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

The error is in your LINQ query - not the code. You need to enable breakpoint - select Debug / Exceptions... and check at the item `[] Common language runtime`. Then when the program throws an exception, it will break at the exception line. You will know how to fix your query.
Or you can post your exception here.

Happy coding.

Comment: Hi, the code flow is ok with no errors...I got the error 500 only when the result for name3 is in the returned object.

Comment: Can you send the exception? it should be detailed - like name3 can't be serialized.

Comment: Hi, please see the Nkosi answer. The problem was solved returning anonymous objects. Thank you.